React component won't re render
I have problem with menu re render, my handleToggleFunction work only for first click, and I got expected animation and behavior, but it works only for first click.. If I would click again nothing is happening and my state wouldn't update. I forgot to mention I am using Tailwind css, but vanila neither. This is my component:
I tried to use useCallback, I wonder if I should use key property somewhere... This is my first react project and I got stuck at the beginning
import { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { FaBars } from "react-icons/fa";

export default function Header() {
  const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = useState(false);

  const liClass = "text-blue-400 text-3xl tracking-wide uppercase";

  const handleToggleMenu = useCallback(() => {
    setIsMenuOpen((prev) => !prev);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div
        onClick={handleToggleMenu}
        className="absolute top-2 right-4 w-7 cursor-pointer"
      >
        <FaBars className="text-red-400 font-bold w-full" />
      </div>

      <menu
        className={`fixed inset-0 w-full h-screen flex justify-center items-center transition-transform duration-1000 ease-in-out ${
          isMenuOpen ? "translate-x-0 opacity-1" : "translate-x-full opacity-0"
        }`}
      >
        <ul className="flex flex-col gap-8">
          <li className={liClass}>Home</li>
          <li className={liClass}>About</li>
          <li className={liClass}>Contact</li>
        </ul>
      </menu>
    </>
  );
}


I don't think handleToggleMenu needs to be in a useCallback since it doesn't rely on state outside itself. Consider removing that?

You also haven't provided a value for dependency array in callback function, so it will be called only on first click.
But if you will remove useCallback, it should work as expected.
https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback#usecallback

setIsMenuOpen is a stable reference so it should work as intended

I tried without callback, also tried to provide dependency, however it works only on first click, I noticed that state is changing when I remove ternary classes from my menu element.

The ternary in the className won't be affecting the state. The state will be changing regardless

Can you please try and create a [mre] so we can reproduce this?

Sorry I am new on stack.. :/ I will try

Here is your updated code
import { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { FaBars } from "react-icons/fa";

export default function Signup() {
  const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = useState(false);

  const liClass = "text-blue-400 text-3xl tracking-wide uppercase";

  const handleToggleMenu = useCallback(() => {
    setIsMenuOpen((prev) => !prev);

  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div
        onClick={handleToggleMenu}
        className="right-4 absolute top-2 z-50 left-0 w-7 cursor-pointer"
      >
        <FaBars className=" text-red-400 top-2 font-bold w-full" />
      </div>

      <menu
        className={`inset-0 w-full h-screen flex justify-center items-center transition-transform duration-1000 ease-in-out ${
          isMenuOpen ? "translate-x-0 opacity-1" : "translate-x-full opacity-0"
        }`}
      >
        <ul className="flex flex-col gap-8">
          <li className={liClass}>Home</li>
          <li className={liClass}>About</li>
          <li className={liClass}>Contact</li>
        </ul>
      </menu>
    </>
  );
}

Note:
when your header menus open then the toggler becomes under the menu so that's why it is not clickable again now I applied z-index so it is working all the time. It is perfectly working on my end.

Thanks bud! It didn't occur to me that I covered the clickable element with a style, thanks a lot :D

Why didn't you put console.log inside the handler to see if it's running?

@Milan You're welcome! No worries, it happens to the best of us. Glad I could help you spot the issue. If you have any more questions or need further assistance, feel free to ask!
